# Wordpress Not Publishing Posts To Custom Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a theme that has a lot of custom templates, like every page. Ridiculous, but for some reason the template I made for the "postings" page is not getting the posts? I have set the post page in reading preferences, and I have set the page to use my template, but it still publishes posts to a default template. Of all the customization I built into this I did not expect the blog part to give me trouble! lol Anyone run into this kind of thing?
Thank you.

Comment: What template does it puplish to? index.php?
Can you post the 'postings' template? Or if its very long, just around the loop

Comment: Yeah it is using index.php
I just read in the codex that you can not use a custom template for the postings page? I had no idea, but that would explain it...

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually to it is to have standard setting in reading preferences.
Build my front-page in index.php
Build a template for blog posts
Add a page and assign the blog post template

Of course you then have a kind of placeholder page sitting amongst the other pages, don't really like that. But it works.